# Rename a PDF based off text in the PDF through the command line in Windows

Tags: batch-file, pdf, command-line

I would like to create a Windows batch file that can accept the name of a file in as a parameter and then search for text within the PDF to rename the file. For example, I have a file called 123.pdf, inside that PDF there is the text "My Name: Paul". I would like to create a new copy of 123.pdf and call it Paul.pdf. I have created the file below but unfortunately it is not working, I think the issue is that it is trying to rename it to "My Name: Paul". The good news is that extracting the PDF text to a txt file is working fine thanks to pdftotext.exe

Please help.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\"
set pdffile=%1
pdftotext.exe %pdffile%.pdf
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /B /L /c:"My Name:" "%sourcedir%\%pdffile%.txt"') DO (

echo %%a

SET myname=%%a

SET myname=myname: =%
SET myname=myname::=%
echo %myname%

echo COPY %pdffile%.pdf %myname%.pdf
COPY %pdffile%.pdf %myname%.pdf
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you are right: you cannot rename a file using a name with `:` in it in Windows because it's the drive/path separator.

For your script, you have to enabled delayed expansion for `myname`, then use `!` instead of `%` in the loop (also fixed a problem when you're stripping spaces & colons from `myname` but not the prefix!).

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\"
set pdffile=%1
pdftotext.exe %pdffile%.pdf
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /B /L /c:"My Name:" "%sourcedir%\%pdffile%.txt"') DO (

echo %%a

SET myname=%%a

rem ok but that doesn't remove My Name prefix
rem SET myname=!myname: =!
rem SET myname=!myname::=!
rem this does:
set myname=!myname:My Name:=!

echo COPY %pdffile%.pdf !myname!.pdf
COPY "%pdffile%.pdf" "!myname!.pdf"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jean! I am getting a syntax error, is this text converting over correctly: set myname=!myname:My Name: =!`

Comment: Hmm... "syntax of the command is incorrect" looks like it is trying to copy to "My Name:123.pdf"

Comment: COPY 123.pdf My Name:123.pdf

Comment: there's no space between colon and digits. See my edited post. `set myname=!myname:My Name:=!` (sorry for all the tries!)

Comment: don't bother, I'll take one in the fridge on your behalf. cheers!

Comment: Why not use the colon as a delimiter and take the 2nd token with the FOR command.